# connecting to sql-server 2005 on another domain through VPN connection

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 dev installed on my machine.

Using "SQL Server Management Studio": How can I connect to a SQL server on another Domain?

Please note that the computer has to be VPN'ed into the Domain I am connecting to.

I have the domain credentials for the machine I will be connecting to.

Please explain briefly as I am new to using sql-server.

Thanks, Voodoo

Comment: Are you able to connect to the machine? What authentication mode?

Comment: Windows Authentication mode. Yes I think I can connect to that machine, how do I veryfy it?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2009/05/04/tip-connecting-to-a-database-using-windows-authentication-with-different-credentials-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx) explains what you need to do.

First get your VPN set up and then you tell Management Studio to run using a different account using runas to launch MS with alternate windows credentials.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try if you can reach the server trought VPN:

(from DOS prompt command)

telnet hostname_mssql_server 1433

1433 is the default port for Microsoft SQL server, if you can not connect to the server ask to the admin the ip address and the port to use.